# Decent ad platforms that don't track

Tags: advertising

Are there ad platforms that don't track?

I want to put a bit of ads on my personal blog for a bit of side money, but I don't want to intrude in my readers' privacy by allowing them to be tracked by the ad platforms. I also don't want bad ads (porn, gambling, and otherwise illegal or deceptive ads).

I know some site owners build their own ad-hosting system, but I don't want to spend that kind of effort if I can avoid it.

Comment: If they don’t track users, how can they stop you from faking users to defraud the advertiser?

Comment: Unfortunately questions asking for [recommendations for sites and resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) like ad platforms are considered off-topic here. You could ask this in our chat room however.

Comment: @dan Thanks for the pointer. Hopefully I can get some recommendations in the chat room.

Comment: Good question. The Do Not Track (DNT) header is the proposed HTTP header field DNT that requests that a web application disable either its tracking or cross-site user tracking (the ambiguity remains unresolved) of an individual user. The Do Not Track header was originally proposed in 2009

Comment: Would it be better if I rephrase the question to center around the technical feasibility of such ad plaforms (no tracking, while being able to generate ads relevant to the page, share revenue with site owner, and still prevent faking users to defraud the advertiser, like @MikeScott brought up), and elicit example ad networks?